# Can marigold extract be used in mosquito repellent ointment?

Tags: natural-remedy, medications, mosquito

I am doing research on mosquito repellent as a part of my college project. I have found various sources of marigold being used as insect repellent such as the following link- 
 https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3385578/

I have not seen use of marigold in commercial mosquito repellent. 
Can marigold extract be used in mosquito repellent ointment?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. From the study you cited it clearly can be used in an ointment.